# Cylindrical coordianates

Tags: calculus

In the following example I need to set up the triple integral but I do not need to evaluate it

I need to set up the triple integral to find the volume of the solid region inside the sphere $ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4 $ and above the upper nappe of the cone $ z^2 = 3x^2 + 3y^2 $

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Triple Integration in vector calc](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870008/triple-integration-in-vector-calc)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$\textrm{Volume} = \int_{\theta = 0}^{2\pi} \int_{r=0}^1 r \left(\int_{z = \sqrt{3(x^2+y^2)}}^{\sqrt{4 -(x^2+y^2)}} 1 \ dz \right) dr \ d\theta$$

$$\\$$

They key, yes is to use cylindrical coordinates. You know the region is bounded above by the sphere and below by the cone so you can get the bounds for $z$. Next, find the intersection which will give you the domain of integration in the plane.

Comment: okay so is that the answer for triple integral for the volume?

Comment: Yes. You are left to evaluate the integral. Once you solve the first integral, use the fact that $x^2+y^2 = r^2$ since in the double integral you've made a coordinate change (hence the ''r'').

Comment: okay awesome so this is the right set up of the integral and from here should be easy to evaluate  thanks

Comment: just waiting for the timer to run up so i can accept it